# Is it possible to find an analytical solution for "x" in this equation?

Tags: optimization, roots, nonlinear-system

In my research I have come across the equation

$$\prod_i^n \left( \frac{a_i}{x} \right)^\frac{b_i}{x} = \prod_i^n (1-d_i)^{(1-b_i)c}$$

Is it possible to obtain $x$ from this analytically, or do I have to search numerically using e.g. a root-finding algorithm?

The solution I seek for $x$ must be strictly positive (in fact all variables are positive), and $b \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I assume that $x>0$, as is the quantity on the right?

Comment: Yes, all variables are strictly positive, and $\beta$ is between 0 and 1 (or can be assumed to be binary).

Comment: Woops! I meant $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it is possible (EDIT: I was wrong), but it can be simplified quite a bit. Do a change of variables $y=1/x$, and take the logarithm of both sides:
$$\sum_i (b_iy)\log(a_iy) = \left(\sum_i b_i\right) y\log y + \left(\sum_i b_i\log a_i\right) y = \log \prod_i^n (1-d_i)^{(1-b_i)c}.$$
So you have a problem of the form $\alpha y\log y + \beta y = \gamma$. That's not going to be difficult to solve numerically. There might be a way to express the solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), but in most computational environments you're not likely to find that implemented. (EDIT: See Robert's formula below; I got the same result from Wolfram Alpha.)

Comment: I have access to an implementation of the Lambert W. Could you help me to find that solution?

Comment: Ha! Robert beat me to it. I was in the process of typing "solve a y Log[y] + b y = c for y" into Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: $$y = {\frac {\gamma}{\alpha} \left( {\rm W} \left({\frac {\gamma}{\alpha}{
{\rm e}^{{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}}}}\right) \right) ^{-1}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does that mean that $$x = \frac{\alpha}{\gamma} \text{W}\left(\frac{\gamma}{\alpha} e^\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)$$?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Comment: So unfortunately this is coming up with negative values of $x$ for some inputs. Is there a way to restrict the output to strictly positive values?

Comment: When the value of $x$ *is* positive, does it satisfy the original equation (to reasonable tolerance)? If so, my guess is that particular combinations of your parameters are infeasible.